# Typescript ExpressJS - injecting services into REST API Controllers

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am attempting an OOP approach to my express rest API with Typescript and having issues composing classes.

The idea is to have a AuthController class that calls a private AuthService class to interact with the database. However, when I attempt to call the AuthService class with the AuthController class, it always returns undefined.

App class which initializes my express app and registers my controllers:

```
class App {
  private app;
  private controllers: Controller[];
  constructor(controllers: Controller[]) {
    this.app = express();
    this.controllers = controllers;
    this.config();
    this.initializeRoutes();
    this.initializeErrorHandler();
  }

  config() {
    console.log("running config");
    this.app.use(cors());
    this.app.use(express.json());
    this.app.use(helmet());
  }

  public listen() {
    this.app.listen(3000);
  }

  initializeRoutes() {
    this.controllers.forEach((controller: any) => {
      this.app.use("/", controller.router);
    });
  }
  initializeErrorHandler() {
    this.app.use(errorMiddleware);
  }
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await connection(); //creates my database connection
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while connecting to the database", error);
    return error;
  }
  const app = new App([new AuthController()]);
  app.listen();
})();
```

here is my AuthController being initialized in my call to `const app = new App([new AuthController()]);`

```
export default class AuthController implements Controller {
  public path = "/api/auth";
  public router = Router();
  private authService: AuthService = new AuthService();

  constructor() {
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }

  public initializeRoutes() {
    //login route
    this.router.post(this.path.concat("/login"), this.login);
    this.router.post(
      this.path.concat("/register"),
      validationMiddleware(CreateUserDto),
      this.register
    );
    this.router.post(this.path.concat("/resetpassword"), this.resetPassword);
    this.router.post(this.path.concat("/newpassword"), this.newPassword);
  }

  public async register(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const userData: CreateUserDto = req.body;
    try {
      let {
        tokens: { xAuthToken, xRefreshToken },
        user,
      } = await this.authService.register(userData);
      res.setHeader("x-auth-token", xAuthToken);
      res.setHeader("x-refresh-token", xRefreshToken);
      res.json(user);
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  }
}
```

and finally AuthService class

```
export class AuthService {
  private userRepo: Repository<User> = getRepository(User);

  constructor() {}

  public async register(userData: CreateUserDto) {
    let foundUser = await this.userRepo.findOne({
      where: { email: userData.email.toLowerCase() },
    });
    console.log(foundUser);
    if (foundUser) {
      throw new EmailInUseException();
    } else {
      console.log(foundUser);
      const user = new User();
      user.email = userData.email.toLowerCase();
      user.password = userData.password;
      await this.userRepo.save(user);
      const tokens = this.createTokens(user);
      return {
        tokens,
        user,
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Anytime I call the AuthService from the AuthController, I receive an 'error cannot read property 'authService' of undefined'.

I have tried changing the code to initialize the AuthService directly `const app = new App([new AuthController(new AuthService()]);` but this doesn't fix the issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The 'this' context was being changed. I switched my 'register' method to an arrow function which fixed the problem

original:

```
class AuthController{


  public async register(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const userData: CreateUserDto = req.body;
    try {
      let {
        tokens: { xAuthToken, xRefreshToken },
        user,
      } = await this.authService.register(userData);
      res.setHeader("x-auth-token", xAuthToken);
      res.setHeader("x-refresh-token", xRefreshToken);
      res.json(user);
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  }

}
```

new:

```
class AuthController{


public register = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const userData: CreateUserDto = req.body;
    try {
      let {
        tokens: { xAuthToken, xRefreshToken },
        user,
      } = await this.authService.register(userData);
      res.setHeader("x-auth-token", xAuthToken);
      res.setHeader("x-refresh-token", xRefreshToken);
      res.json(user);
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  };
}
```